# trying to build a bot that fetches latest trends globally

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm a student learning Python and working on building my portfolio.   I'm currently trying to fetch global Twitter trends using the WOEID (Where On Earth Identifier) with config.ini. However, I'm running into a 401 response error, even though I'm using a free account i should be able to trending tweets with this code. Can anyone provide some guidance or suggest a solution for this issue?

```
# Define a function to fetch trends by location using the Twitter API
def get_trends_by_location(woeid):
    #  a GET request to the trends/place endpoint with the specified woeid
    url = f"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id={woeid}"
    #  Twitter API authentication headers
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        trends_data = response.json()
        # Extract and return the trends
        return trends_data[0]['trends']
    else:
        print("Error fetching trends:", response.status_code)
        return []

# Get global trending topics (change the woeid for other locations or 1 global)
trending_topics = get_trends_by_location(1)
....
```

However, I'm running into a 401 response error, even though I'm using a free account.
401 :
There was a problem authenticating your request. This could be due to missing or incorrect authentication credentials. This may also be returned in other undefined circumstances.

Check that you are using the correct authentication method and that your credentials are correct.